# jQuery JSON Parsing Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a web page that returns this JSON when called:

```
[{"id":"53","desc":"Roberts"}]
```

I am using this jQuery to call it by AJAX:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: rootPath + "data/topology/stations",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { areaID: $("#lbxArea").val () },
    success: function (data) {
        // Use data for actions
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert (textStatus);
        alert (errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I used Firebug to confirm that the data being returned is what I put on top. Despite that, I fall into the `error` callback and first see `parsererror` in an alert box, and then I see

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'
```

I tried having the service return

```
{"list":[{"id":"53","desc":"Roberts"}]}
```

but that didn't change anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery won't parse my JSON from AJAX query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249692/jquery-wont-parse-my-json-from-ajax-query)

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: No, @sje397, this does not look like a duplicate of that one at all. In that question, the JSON was clearly malformed (no quotes around property names, etc).  The JSON shown here in this question looks fine.

Comment: jQuery 1.6.2 (minimized)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whats the response content-type?!
Try testing this response using this:

[Getting the response content-type from jQuery.Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051434/getting-the-response-content-type-from-jquery-post/4051705#4051705)

also try not having the dataType: 'json' and check the return!

Comment: The content type is 'text/html'.

Comment: set the response.contentType to "application/json" and see what happends

Comment: I dropped the dataType and tried to parse the data manually in the success function (which I could now get into), but I get the same problem. It looks like my JSON is getting HTML encoded. How do I fix that?

Comment: @Nik set the contentyType to "application/json"

Answer (score 2):

**Well**, I've spent some time on this question, but I'll make something that will serve those who have this problem.

The mistake is in wanting a property accesder response coming from PHP, introducing the following message:

```
*SyntaxError: JSON. parse: expected property name or '}'*
```

What you should do is convert JSON response to this is to use the function JSON.parse (data); inside we pass the response variable "data". I will comment a bit the code for better understanding:

```
   success: function (data) {/ / on success ..     
var json = JSON.parse (data);/ / Convert the JSON format input
console.log (JSON.parse (data));/ / explore the answer
  alert ("" + json.msj);/ / Variable Access Testing with alert
....
```

Everything seems fine up here, however is dimensioned present the error, then that is because the way it is performing the response from PHP.

Here is a practical way to do it right:

We use json_encode function to return the data in JSON format, within the function passed an associative array with the variables that are required, Example:

```
echo json_encode (array ('success' => true, 'msg' => 'Hello registered user!'));
```

After these variables acquire client side without any problem, and simply, here a nitrous-code:

```
$. ajax ({/ / create an AJAX call ...
data: $ (this). serialize (), / / get the form data
type: $ (this). attr ('method'), / / GET or POST
url: $ (this). attr ('action'), / / the file to call

cache: false,
success: function (data) {/ / on success ..

var json = JSON.parse (data);

$ ('# created'). html (json.msj) / / update the DIV
```

I hope will be helpful ... any questions feel free to ask ...

Answer (score 1):

You can install a Firefox add-on "JSONView". Maybe this gives you more information about the JSON string.

If you don't see anything (special JSON markup), you probaby miss a JSON header.

---

**Edit:**
Firebug 1.4+ should show a JSON tab at a request.

Comment: +1:lol "If you don't see anything, you probaby miss a JSON header."

Comment: I actually mean the hierarchical markup including syntax highlighting.